# How to move nested class in superclass in java?

Tags: java, class, nested, abstract, superclass

I need to refactor class extracting abstract superclass.
E.g.

```
UpperClass {
NestedClass {
UpperClass.this.someMethod();
}
}
```

Like:

```
AbstractUpperClass {
    NestedClass {
  ?????.this.someMethod();
  }
}
```

After I plan inherit AbstractUpperClass in 2 classes UpperClass1 and UpperClass2.
But I don't know how to refactor this inner class because it inovokes method of enclosing class. Does it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "upper" do you mean "super", or is this some sort of Diamond Jubilee celebration software you're writing? 8=\/

Comment: Just use AbstractUpperClass.this.someMethod()

Comment: Your code is unintelligible. Can you provide a valid [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is knowing how the inner class works. It's essentially just a "normal", static class, but whose constructor implicitly gets a reference to the enclosing class. So, this:

```
public class TopLevel {

    public void go() {
        new Inner().bar();
    }

    public void foo() { }

    public class Inner {
        public void bar() {
            TopLevel.this.foo();
        }        
    }
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
public class TopLevel {

    public void go() {
        new Inner(this).bar();          // explicitly passing in "this"
    }

    public void foo() { }

    public static class Inner {
        private final TopLevel parent;  // note that we have this new field

        public Inner(TopLevel parent) { // note this new constructor
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void bar() {             // we use the explicit reference instead
            parent.foo();               // of the implicit TopLevel.this
        }        
    }
}
```

So, with all that said, the way to refactor your inner class to be a top-level class is to add an explicit field referencing the `UpperClass` instance, and passing this reference into the `NestedClass` constructor. In other words, be like that second code snippet instead of the first.